# Merging Landsat 4, 5, and 7 Data for Simple Composite

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-7, landsat-5, composite

I'm attempting to merge Landsat 4, Landsat 5, and Landsat 7 imagery into a single image collection in Google Earth Engine, in hopes of running simpleComposite() on the entire collection.

```
var geo = ee.Geometry.Polygon([
  [[-144.887,61.468], 
   [-141.712,61.468], 
   [-141.712,62.454], 
   [-144.887,62.454], 
   [-144.887,61.468]]
]);

Map.centerObject(geo, 8);
var startDate = '1999-01-01';
var endDate = '2000-01-01';

var ls45_bands = ['B1', 'B2',  'B3',  'B4',  'B5', 'B7', 'B6']; 
var ls7_bands = ['B1', 'B2',  'B3',  'B4',  'B5', 'B7', 'B6_VCID_2'];
var std_names = ['B1', 'B2',  'B3',  'B4',  'B5', 'B7', 'B6']; 

var ls4 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT04/C01/T1").select(ls45_bands, std_names);
var ls5 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1").select(ls45_bands, std_names);
var ls7 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1").select(ls7_bands, std_names);

var lsAll = ee.ImageCollection(ls4.merge(ls5).merge(ls7));
var lsAll = ee.ImageCollection(lsAll)
      .filterBounds(geo)
      .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(6, 8, 'month'))
      .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 50);

var composite = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleComposite({
  collection: lsAll,
}).clip(geo);  

Map.addLayer(composite, null, 'composite');
```

I renamed the relevant bands properly as outlined here:

[Merging raw data from Landsat 5, Landsat 7 and Landsat 8](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/338915/merging-raw-data-from-landsat-5-landsat-7-and-landsat-8)

However, I get this error:

```
composite: Tile error: Error in map(ID=2_LE07_066017_19990818): Landsat.simpleCloudScore: No band named 'B6_VCID_2'. Available band names: [B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B7, B6].
```

It seems that simpleComposite() identifies if an image is from Landsat 7 and requires that the B6_VCID_2 band is there in order to calculate simpleCloudScore. How should I merge these collections so that I can apply simpleComposite() to all of the images? I did find a workaround where I took the Simple Composite of Landsat 4/5 and Landsat 7 individually, and then took the median of these two images. However, it fails when one of the collections is empty. The code for that is [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/6b5a82542b2513fdf377c9d1721a5f78).

Sorry if this question is poorly asked. I'm a high schooler new to GEE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SimpleComposite basically just runs SimpleCloudScore and does a qualityMosaic of the result.  You can do that on your own.  There's a javascript version of the cloud score in the [Examples section](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=Examples%3AImage%20Collection%2FSimple%20Cloud%20Score)